# Parsing JSONObject to AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, json

To parse the following JSONObject:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "error_warning": "",
        "shipping_methods": {
            "free": {
                "title": "Free Shipping",
                "quote": {
                    "free": {
                        "code": "free.free",
                        "title": "Free Shipping",
                        "cost": 0,
                        "tax_class_id": 0,
                        "text": "Rs0"
                    }
                },
                "sort_order": "",
                "error": false
            },
            "flat": {
                "title": "Flat Rate",
                "quote": {
                    "flat": {
                        "code": "flat.flat",
                        "title": "Flat Shipping Rate",
                        "cost": "50",
                        "tax_class_id": "9",
                        "text": "Rs50"
                    }
                },
                "sort_order": "1",
                "error": false
            }
        },
        "code": "",
        "comment": ""
    }
}
```

I am using the following code:

```
JSONObject d = response.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject ja = d.getJSONObject("shipping_methods");
Iterator x = ja.keys();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
int i = 0;
while (x.hasNext()){
    String key = (String) x.next();
    JSONObject ja1 = ja.getJSONObject(key);
    Iterator x1 = ja1.keys();
    while (x1.hasNext()){
        String key1 = (String) x1.next();
        JSONObject ja2 = ja1.getJSONObject("quote");
        Iterator x2 = ja2.keys();
        while (x2.hasNext()){
            String key2 = (String) x2.next();
            JSONObject ja3 = ja2.getJSONObject(key2);
            jsonArray.put(ja3.get("code"));
        }
    }
}
Log.e("AAA",jsonArray.toString());
```

But I need to create an AlertDialog with select option for shipping methods. As the shipping method array is dynamic and depends upon the address of user. So I can't hard code the keys on shipping_methods. Is there best way to parse this type of JSONObject to make AlertDialog.

My Alert Dialog Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
builder.setTitle("Shipping Methods");
CharSequence[] cs = slist.toArray(new CharSequence[slist.size()]);
builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // the user clicked on colors[which]
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Comment: "*Is there best way to parse this type of JSONObject*" -- Yeah, it would make your life easier to use Gson, probably, then you'd need to populate a Spinner with an ArrayAdapter for the select options

Comment: Are you not making use of java Objects?

Comment: @cricket_007 trying Gson now.